# Push an array within the object of an array at specific index in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array like

```
arr = [
  {name:{"id": 1},data:{"dataVal": value1}},
  {name:{"id": 2},data:{"dataVal": value2}},
  {name:{"id": 3},data:{"dataVal": value3}}
]
```

How can i push an array within that object at specific index like
that i have an array that i want to push at specific index

`let newArr =[]`

the final result after pushing like (when pushed at index 0)

```
arr = [
  {name:{"id": 1},data:{"dataVal": value1},newArr:[]},
  {name:{"id": 2},data:{"dataVal": value2}},
  {name:{"id": 3},data:{"dataVal": value3}}
]
```

Please help How to achieve it?

Comment: The word *push* is generally used for arrays, not for objects. What you are searching for is a property assignment. `arr[0].newArr = []` or if the value is present in the `newArr` variable then `arr[0].newArr = newArr`

Answer (score 2):

My Answer:

```js
const arr = [
  { name: { "id": 1 }, data: { "dataVal": "value1" } },
  { name: { "id": 2 }, data: { "dataVal": "value2" } },
  { name: { "id": 3 }, data: { "dataVal": "value3" } },
]

Object.assign(arr[0], { newArr: [] })
console.log(arr)
```

Answer (score 2):

Object is a reference type, so you can get the target object from the `array` by `index` and then update its `newArr` property.

```js
let arr = [{
  name: {
    "id": 1
  },
  data: {
    "dataVal": 'value1'
  }
}, {
  name: {
    "id": 2
  },
  data: {
    "dataVal": 'value2'
  }
}, {
  name: {
    "id": 3
  },
  data: {
    "dataVal": 'value3'
  }
}]




const update = (array, index, property, value) => {
  array[index][property] = value;
}

update(arr, 0, "newArr", [])

console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this simple utility function.

```js
const newArr = [1, 2, 3]
const arr = [{
    name: {
      "id": 1
    },
    data: {
      "dataVal": "value1"
    }
  }, {
    name: {
      "id": 2
    },
    data: {
      "dataVal": "value2"
    }
  },
  {
    name: {
      "id": 3
    },
    data: {
      "dataVal": "value3"
    }
  }
]

function insertArr(ar, i, newAr) {
  ar[i] = { ...ar[i],
    newAr
  }
  return ar
}
console.log(insertArr(arr, 1, newArr))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use map method with condition that compares `targetIndex` with the current element index (`teranry` syntax `?` ). If the condition is true it will use spread operator to to merge element with your `newArr`, otherwise it will return the unchanged element.

```js
const arr = [
  {name:{"id": 1},data:{"dataVal": "value1"}},
  {name:{"id": 2},data:{"dataVal": "value2"}},
  {name:{"id": 3},data:{"dataVal": "value3"}}
];

const newArr = [];
const targetIndex=0
const result = arr.map((el, idx) => idx === targetIndex ? { ...el, newArr } : el);
console.log(result)
```